# Three dimensional Radon transform

Tags: analysis

I'm studying plane wave spectrum in time domain (Yaghijan-Hansen) for acoustic and electromagnetic fields.
In a paragraph of the book I'm reading (*Plane wave theory of time domain fields* by Thorkild Hansen and A. Yaghjian, page 192) it is written:

$$T(\xi,\eta,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(\mathbf{r}_0,t+\xi x_0+\eta y_0) \,\mathrm{d}x_0\, \mathrm{d}y_0.$$

"The time-domain function $T(\xi,\eta,t)$ is a space-time Radon transform of the time-domain pressure" (that is $p$). But I don't understand why. I'm sorry, but I'm actually studying the Radon transform and I don't know all its equivalents representation.

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete reference?  What book are you reading?  Who is (are) the author(s)?  Is there a particular page that you are looking at?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The book is "Plane wave theory of time domain fields" by Thorkild Hansen, A. Yaghjian. page 192. Thank you